# Searching with strncasecmp

Tags: c, string, search

I want to search through a sentence and then check if a certain word is contained within it. Using the strncasecmp function I can find if the word exists only if it exists in the beginning of the sentence.
How would I find a word, if it lies in the middle of a sentence?

So far I have:

```
while (fgets(buffer, 1000, ifp) != NULL)
    for (i = 0; i < numberTerms; i++){
        len = strlen(term[i]);
        if (strncasecmp(buffer,term[i],len) == 0){
            printf("Term: %s\n", term[i]);
```

But...

```
The dog jumped over the fence
```

"Over" would not be found if I searched for it. However if "The" was being searched, it would be found.
Is there a way I can do what I need?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `strstr` or `strcasestr` (for case-insensitive searching).  The latter is non-standard (as is `strncasecmp`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
    strcasestr(const char *big, const char *little);